# Formatting a date in PHP returned from SQL 2008 datetime field

Tags: php

I'm having issues trying to parse a datetime field that I am returning in an SQL query. I was initially getting errors about it not being able to display it as a string but added the format part below and it at least displayed.

```
<td>".$frontpageresultarray['SubmitDate']->format(DATE_RSS)."</td>
```

If I do that, it works but I don't get the format I want. I need really DD MM YY HH,MM and I have now idea how to go about it. I need to be able to do calculations on the date later in the script so I can't really just make it a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what format is it in right now?

Comment: In the SQL 2008 database it is in datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dateString = $frontpageresultarray['SubmitDate']->format(DATE_RSS);
if($dateObject = new DateTime($dateString)){
// dateString was accepted
// now do something like $dateObject->diff($otherDateObject); to calculate the difference between the $dateObject and $otherDateObject

}else{
// date couldn't be converted
// refere to [date formats][1] for possible formats to use with DateTime
}
```

another approcha would be to use

```
$timestamp = strtotime(string $dateString);
$timestamp2 = strtotime(string $otherDateString);
$difference_in_seconds = $timestamp - $timestamp2;

$time_converted = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($dateString)); //takes the date in $time reads it converts it to unix timestamp and converts this timestamp via date back to string
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `date()` function. It permits to format dates and times in everything you want.

Comment: All that seems to do is format the current date I don't see a way of using the function to reformat an existing string.

Comment: You can convert it to a timestamp, and then format it as you want with the date function.